# Symfony2 known bugs and issues

Tags: symfony

As the name of the post says, I want to know what are the known issues of symfony2 package.

This is because I'm considering to make the switch from **Symfony 1.4** to **2** in my company.

But as my company develops high quality, big projects for big clients, it is of my interest to know what are the issues i might find.

I know that a year ago symfony2 had major issues with forms and doctrine, but a year has passed and i would like to know with what i can count and if it is worth to make the change.

Comment: Definitely start new projects with SF 2

Comment: Any bug or issue that i should be aware of?

Comment: From my experience, both SF2 and Doctrine are pretty mature projects and get the things done. Also, there are now many website running symfony 2 ( cf http://fabien.potencier.org/article/65/why-symfony ). You should just document yourself on SF2 and Doctrine2 architectures, as for example, Doctrine 2 is an ORM and come with its pro and cons.

Comment: All Symfony 2 known bugs are reported in the [GitHub's issues panel](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues?direction=desc&labels=Bug&milestone=&page=1&sort=created&state=open) of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source of information would be the [Symfony GitHub-repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony):

All issues: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues
Open bugs: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues?labels=Bug&page=1&state=open